# Attribute error on Django REST framework, 'Quiz' object has no attribute 'question'

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

These are my models

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    difficulty = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Question(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text


class Choice(models.Model):
    options = models.TextField()
    is_correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

class QuizResult(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.IntegerField()
    date_taken = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def _str_(self):
        return f"{self.user.username} - {self.quiz.title} - {self.score}"
```

And here is my serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from ..models import Quiz, Question, Choice

class ChoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Choice
        fields = ['options', 'is_correct']


class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    choices = ChoiceSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['text', 'choices']


class QuizSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    questions = QuestionSerializer(source = 'question',many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Quiz
        fields = ['title', 'topic', 'difficulty', 'questions', 'created_by']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        questions_data = validated_data.pop('question')
        quiz = Quiz.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for question_data in questions_data:
            choices_data = question_data.pop('choices')
            question = Question.objects.create(quiz=quiz, **question_data)

            for choice_data in choices_data:
                Choice.objects.create(question=question, **choice_data)

        return quiz
```

When I send a post request to `QuizCreateAPIView` it shows an error

```
 Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `questions` on serializer `QuizSerializer`.
        The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Quiz` instance.
        Original exception text was: 'Quiz' object has no attribute 'question'
```

My Quiz model has no attribute called question. But it is vice versa. In my Question model I have a foreign key of Quiz model. I dont know how to implement this.

How can I relate the Quiz and Question model?

My request body looks like this:-

```
{
    "title": "My Quiz",
    "topic": "Python",
    "difficulty": 3,
    "created_by" : 2,
    "questions": [
        {
            "text": "What is Python?",
            "choices": [
                {
                    "options": "A snake",
                    "is_correct": false
                },
                {
                    "options": "A programming language",
                    "is_correct": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you please share details of the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Quiz` is related to `Question`, just you need to add [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) here:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='question')
```